# Is the standard Python implementation considered as a programming language or a scripting language?

Tags: python

Is calling the standard Python implementation a Programming Language justified?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As mentioned in [What’s the difference between Scripting and Programming Languages?](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/whats-the-difference-between-scripting-and-programming-languages/) article:

> Basically, all scripting languages are programming languages. The
>   theoretical difference between the two is that scripting languages do
>   not require the compilation step and are rather interpreted. For
>   example, normally, a C program needs to be compiled before running
>   whereas normally, a scripting language like JavaScript or PHP need not
>   be compiled.

**Applications of Scripting Languages** :

1. To automate certain tasks in a program
2. Extracting information from a data set
3. Less code intensive as compared to traditional programming languages

**Applications of Programming Languages** :

1. They typically run inside a parent program like scripts
2. More compatible while integrating code with mathematical models
3. Languages like JAVA can be compiled and then used on any platform

Also, as mentioned in another article [Difference Between Scripting Language and Programming Language](http://www.avigma.com/scripting-language-programming-language/):

> A scripting language generally sits behind some programming language.
>   Scripting languages generally have less access to the computer’s
>   native abilities since they only run on a subset of the programming
>   language.Scripting languages are generally slower than programming
>   languages.

More details from Quora's post [Why is Python called "a scripting language"?](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-Python-called-a-scripting-language):

> Just because something is interpreted doesn't mean it's a scripting
>   language -- after all, Python can be compiled. And standard Python
>   compiles Python code into bytecode and interprets that, just like
>   Java. But you never see Java called a "scripting language." Also,
>   there are C interpreters out there. If anyone cares to put in the
>   effort, any language can be either compiled or interpreted.

**Conclusion**

> Python is considered a scripting language because of a historical blur
>   between scripting languages and general purpose programming languages.
>   In fact, Python is not a scripting language, but a general purpose
>   programming language that also works nicely as a scripting language.

Comment: The conclusion was quite ambiguous.

Comment: Back when CPU were 10-100 million times slower in the 1980s you had to have everything optimized for the CPU so a "general purpose language" needed ahead of time compilers, but starting from the early 90s the bottleneck in coding shifted from the CPU to the hard drive and to programmer time.  Also dynamic (JIT) compilers were really bad.  Today what used to be called scripting languages are the general purpose languages, while low-level languages like C++ are actually special purpose languages.